# How do I turn values into columns and put counts into them?

Tags: sql-server

I made a table called `tbl` with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (
      `Year` int, 
      `Album` varchar(255),
      `Artist` varchar(255),
      `Label` varchar(255),
      `Genre` varchar(255),
      `id` int
    )
;

INSERT INTO tbl
    (
      `Year`,
      `Album`,
      `Artist`,
      `Label`,
      `Genre`,
      `id`
    )
VALUES
    (1990, "Greatest Hits", "The Best", "Least Def", "hip hop", 123),
    (1990, "Greatest Hits", "The Best", "Roofless", "hip hop", 123),
    (1990, "4-Boyz", "3 Guyz", "Pacific", "pop-dance", 23),
    (1990, "4-Boyz", "3 Guyz", "Atlantic", "pop-dance", 23)
;
```

I will insert more rows later that will have different artists and genres.

I want to run a query to show me the count of genres for each year, without double counting because of the `Label` column. I want this:

```
Year, hip hop, pop-dance
1990, 1, 1
```

What query must I run to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot based upon the genre.  As you will not know the number of genres, you'll need to make it dynamic using dynamic SQL.  See below for an example.

You can change the aggregation to meet your needs. In the below example i'm counting id and grouping by year.

**Before Pivot**

[image: Before]

**Code**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (
      Year int, 
      Album varchar(255),
      Artist varchar(255),
      Label varchar(255),
      Genre varchar(255),
      id int
    )
;

INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES
    (1990, 'Greatest Hits', 'The Best', 'Least Def', 'hip hop', 123),
    (1990, 'Greatest Hits', 'The Best', 'Roofless', 'hip hop', 123),
    (1990, '4-Boyz', '3 Guyz', 'Pacific', 'pop-dance', 23),
    (1990, '4-Boyz', '3 Guyz', 'Atlantic', 'pop-dance', 23)


Select * from tbl

Declare @Query_ nvarchar(MAX)
Declare @Cols_For_Pivot_ nvarchar(MAX) 

--Get unique list of metrics in Var_Col for pivot.
SELECT @Cols_For_Pivot_= COALESCE(@Cols_For_Pivot_ + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Genre)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Genre FROM dbo.tbl) AS PivotExample


SET   @Query_ = 
    N'SELECT Year, ' +   @Cols_For_Pivot_ + '
    FROM [dbo].[tbl] 
    PIVOT( Count(id) 
          FOR Genre IN (' + @Cols_For_Pivot_ + ')) AS P
    GROUP BY Year, ' +   @Cols_For_Pivot_ + ''


--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query_
```

**After Pivot**

[image: After]

Comment: Thanks. I've also just been updated that the table won't be updated. All the data will be inserted. How would I do this, as well?

Comment: Well, if its not going to change, you could just hard code the variable @Cols_For_Pivot.  That variable is just a comma separated list based upon the distinct values in the column you would like to pivot by.  In your case that would be genre.

Comment: Then I would just do `SELECT @Cols_For_Pivot_= "Genre"`?

Comment: @Username 1 min, ill update it based on your exact example.

Comment: @Username I saw you just tagged the question with MySQL.  I don't think this will work for MySQL. :(     This solution is for SQL Server